# Toggle buttons toggled, but do not -look- toggled

Tags: python, pygobject

I have some Python + PYGobject code I've been using for years.

Today it's having problems, and I don't know why.

If I run it, it looks fine.  But if I click a toggle button, the button doesn't look clicked.  But if I continue clicking as though the button were correct, things function fine.

Also, the scrollbars no longer look like they're doing anything, but in reality they are.  That is, if I scroll down, and guess where a button should be, it works, but it doesn't look like any scrolling happened.

This evening I tested this program on two Linux Mint 18.2 systems.  One is running Cinnamon on a physical framebuffer, the other is running fvwm2 under VNC.  Strangely, the one running Cinnamon has the problem, but the fvwm2 one works fine - despite them both using exactly the same Python code.

The actual code can be found at http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/hcm/trunk

BTW, I checked out a much older version of the same program and tested that, and I still got the same problem - buttons don't look clicked but are, and scrolled areas don't look scrolled but are.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that if I remote display (tunneled over ssh), so I'm running on the fvwm2 system, but displaying instead back to the Cinnamon system, the scroll bars work for a while, and then get stuck.

Comment: This isn't precisely an answer, but I reinstalled my system with Mint 18.3 (it was Mint 18.2), and the problem went away.